# Qt - How to rotate a QLabel inside Qt Creator UI Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, gui-designer

The problem is pretty simple. I have a `QLabel` object which gets a picture via setting a resource to the `pixmap` attribute. Because the Qt Designer is the best GUI Designer of the world (ever) it shows the picture rotated 90° left:

[image: QLabel which I want to rotate]

How can I rotate the QLabel?

I also would be happy if somebody could tell me why the Qt Creator does rotate the image itself. Windows (the best OS ever) says it has a width of 88 px and a height of 923 px:

Here `Breite == Width` and `Höhe == Height` (Höhe, Breite is German (Best language ever)):

[image: Width and Height]

I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I were you I would rotate the image and then set the label pixmap. Possibly not the best solution, but it works.

To rotate the image you could do something like this:

```
QPixmap original;
// load original from your source or take it from somewhere
QImage srcImg = original.toImage();
QPoint center = srcImg.rect().center();
QMatrix matrix;
matrix.translate(center.x(), center.y());
matrix.rotate(90);
QImage dstImg = srcImage.transformed(matrix);
QPixmap dstPix = QPixmap::fromImage(dstImg); //New pixmap rotated
```

Now you have the new `QPixmap` rotated ready to be set as the `QLabel` pixmap.

If you have the original image on your computer an even dumber and easier solution would be to rotate the original image with any image software and directly load it.

```
QPixmap verticalPixmap('/path/to/image/rotatedImage.jpg');
```

Comment: Thx... What I did not mention was that I actually rotated the image with _Paint_ but unfortunately Qt put it in like the original.... I actually had to copy the picture.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to copy the picture after rotating it because the Qt Creator will (why ever) not adopt the rotation...